# How would an typescript interface for this object look like?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array of objects and I need to make an interface for it?
The array of objects :

```
[
{
"_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
"index": 0,
"email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Wendi Mooney"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
  }
  ]
  },
  {
"_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
"index": 1,
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Janine Barrett"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Odonnell Savage"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Patty Owen"
  }
  ]
  },
```

Also I sent this object as props in another component, `<SomeComponent componentData = {data} >`

Comment: Interface as in a UI? Or interface as in a typescript interface?

Comment: My bad, shoudve added typescript in the title so its more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it down from the inside out...

```ts
interface Name {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Entry {
  _id: string;
  index: number;
  email?: string;
  nameList: Name[]; // or Array<Name>
}

interface SomeComponentProps {
  componentData: Entry[];
}
```

You could inline the whole thing but IMO that looks messy

```ts
interface SomeComponentProps {
  componentData: Array<{
    _id: string; 
    index: number;
    email?: string;
    nameList: Array<{
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }>;
  }>;
}
```